# NAS Linkstation not waking up on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nas

I Have a Buffallo Linkstation NAS. It have 3 power settings: Off, Auto and On.
When set to Auto, it sleeps automatically after a while. When a computer running NAS Navigator program is on, it automatically wakes up. This was working fine on my Windows 7 setup, but after i installed Windows 10 it stopped. I have to use "On" to force it to start.

So how can I diagnose or fix this?

I've already changed network from public to private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess changing network from public to private did the job, i just had to restart.

To do this:

- Go to start, type "Homegroup", and open it.
- Once in homegroup, click "change network location"
- A popup will say your computer will be discoverable, click Yes

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may have this issue but isn’t able to resolve by just making the pc discoverable:

For my win10 pc connected to a Buffalo LinkStation Duo LS-WXL first I confirmed that NAS PM Service is started in services.msc per some other info I found on the buffalo site.

Then I checked my firewall settings and found that I had to add NAS Power management Service to the list and check marked it for private networks. This exe is within the Buffalo->NASNavi directory, wherever you installed the NAS software and it’s named nassvc.exe.

I rebooted and my NAS is now responding correctly to the auto function.